# Angular http 'get' from a flask local server fails

Tags: angular, rest, api, http, flask

I'm building a web server using python Flask and a client using Angular 2, and trying to make Rest communication between the two.
It seems like my server is just fine, since when I enter it's ip:port as a url, the desired information appears in the browser, moreover when i test it with an outer http request mock (Postman) the information is also transferred.
Also, my client app seems fine too, while getting a response from a "real" site actually works (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 returns the desired json).
Even though the two apps works individually, when trying to send a get request from my server to my client, the operation fails.

Here is my client app.component.ts code (192.168.14.10:52225 is the ip:port where the server is running):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {     
  msg: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMsg() {
    this.http.get('http://192.168.14.10:52225').subscribe(data => {
      this.msg = 'YAY!!';
    })}
}
```

And here is my server code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    HOST = '192.168.14.10'
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, PORT, debug=True)
```

Comment: How exactly does it fail? Is there any error message send to the client, maybe an error code?

Comment: the request isn't sent, and i know that because when i put breakpoint inside the get function, it is not reached.
In the client, i get an HttpErrorResponse after calling subscribe function.
If i set another parameter to the subcribe function, which is the failure lambda, i enter this function.

Comment: because you are accessing a different domain than where your client files come from this may be a CORS related issue (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS]) for more info). The request is probably send, but it fails, which is why you enter the failure function. HttpErrorResponse probably has some more information on what went wrong, an error code or a more detailed message, this is probably important to find out what's going on

Comment: Fixed it, added the following lines:
    from flask_cors import CORS
    cors = CORS(app)